# Prove that $\mu(a, b)= \mu(1, b/a)$.

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

Let $n$ be a positive integer and consider the partially ordered set $(X_n, \;|\; )$, where
$X_n = \{1, 2, ... ,n\}$ and the partial order is that of divisibility. Let a and b be
positive integers in $X_n$ , where $a \mid b$. Prove that $\mu(a, b) = \mu(1, b/a)$, where $\mu$ is the Möbius function of the partially ordered set $X_n$.

[image]

Comment: Also add the reference (and the relevant page) this exercise. That way, members of the MSE help you.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that the definition of $\mu$ in your problem is the one given in this wiki article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incidence_algebra

Hint: $\mu(a,b)$ is defined only with reference to elements of $[a,b]$. (Here we use interval notation in the sense of the partial order of divisibility. So $c \in [a,b]$ if $a \vert c$ and $c \vert b$). This is a sub poset of $X_n$ and it is clear that $\mu\lvert_{[a,b]}(a,b) = \mu(a,b)$. Similarly it is clear that $\mu(1, b/a) = \mu\vert_{[1,b/a]}(1,b/a)$.

Therefore in order to prove that $\mu(a,b) = \mu(1, b/a)$, it is sufficient to construct an order preserving bijection between $[a,b]$ and $[1, b/a]$. Can you think of good candidates for such a function?

Comment: Nitpick: you mean "poset isomorphism" (i.e., "order preserving bijection with order preserving inverse"), not just "order preserving bijection".